# How to get nearest places based on a google placeID?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm working on an `android application`, which gets a place ID after the user selects a place name from the google `autocomplete textbox` and then further compares with the database(I had created a database with some placeID and place info) and returns data with matching placeID.

Now, what I need to do is retrieve not only the matching records but also nearest places according to the place ID received from the user input. How do I achieve it? Please help me out guys. Regards,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place has the [getLatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getLatLng()) method which returns "the location of this Place".

To retrieve nearby places, you should pass the location of the place to the Places API Web Service method called [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests). Also, you should specify the radius ("Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results").

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. Exactly what I did!